# Qt How to add dynamic resource files to project without using .qrc?

Tags: c++, qt, resources, relative-path

My qt project is like this. While the program is running, the "config.xml" will be edited, then the "run.bat" file will be called and produce a lot of data under this folder.

BTW, The size of output data may be over 100GB. I don't have to use them in the program.

```
│  mainWindow.cpp
│  mainWindow.ui
│  mainWindow.h
│  
└─Resource
    ├─bin
    │  │  core.exe
    │  │  gencase.exe
    │          
    └─work
        ├─task1
        │  │  config.xml
        │  │  run.bat
        │  └─ output
        │      │  datafiles
        │ 
        ├─task2
        └─...
```

I want to easily use the relative path of these files, so the "run.bat" can call the "core.exe" and show the output data.

But the files under the work folder are big and should be editable, I don't think adding all the files into .qrc is a good idea.

I don't know how to handle this situation.

Comment: `The files under the work folder will be changed,` - what does this mean? What exactly do you want to add to your resource file?

Comment: You want to include files in .qrc if those files are used by your application in any way. Read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. While the program is running, the "config.xml" will be edited, then the "run.bat" file will be called and produce a lot of data under this folder.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your program will edit `config.xml` and execute `run.bat`. If so, you are already able to locate these files. It should be relatively easy to locate the subfolder `output`.

Comment: I use the absolute path for now, so I can achieve these functions separately.  But for the " integral process" and "release software", I should use the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Resource files (.qrc) are for static resources (i.e. available at compile time).

Files created during runtime are often stored inside one of the following locations:

- QStandardPaths::TempLocation
- QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation
- QStandardPaths::CacheLocation
- QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation
- QStandardPaths::GenericConfigLocation

See [`QStandardPaths`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstandardpaths.html) for more information.

Storing those files relative to your program executable is often undesirable, as this location is often not writable for the end user (but may be handy in some cases).

If the user should be able to run or edit those files with an external editor, storing these files in a subfolder of the `QStandardPaths::HomeLocation` may be a good idea too. In that case, it may be desirable to allow the user to optionally change this location.